# Sending a email notification to other emails using nodemailer, but server closing prematurely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodemailer

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const cors = require('cors');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmetCsp = require('helmet-csp');
const winston = require('winston');

const homeRoutes = require('./routes/home');
const giftRegistryRoutes = require('./routes/giftregistry');
const locationRoutes = require('./routes/location');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 100,
});
app.use(limiter);

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log', maxsize: 1048576, level: 'info' })
    ]
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid JSON payload' });
    }
    next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    logger.info(`Request from ${req.ip} to ${req.originalUrl}`);
    next();
});

app.use(
    helmetCsp({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com']
        }
    })
);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    logger.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'yahoo',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.app_password,
    },
    logger: true,
    debug: true,
});

transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Nodemailer verification error:', error);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('Nodemailer is ready to send emails:', success);
    }
});

const validate = [
    body('first_name').notEmpty().withMessage('First name is required'),
    body('last_name').notEmpty().withMessage('Last name is required'),
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Valid email is required'),
    body('attending').isBoolean().withMessage('Attending should be boolean'),
    body('guestName').optional().isString().withMessage('Guest name should be a string')
];

app.post('/api/rsvp', validate, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Received RSVP request:', req.body);

        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const { first_name, last_name, email, attending, guestName } = req.body;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            to: 'provided_email.com',
            subject: 'New RSVP Submission',
            text: `New RSVP Submission:\n\nName: ${first_name} ${last_name}\nEmail: ${email}\nAttending: ${attending ? 'Yes' : 'No'}\nGuest Name: ${guestName || 'N/A'}`,
        };

        console.log('Mail Options:', mailOptions);

        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

        console.log('Email sent:', info);

        if (info.rejected.length > 0 || !info.response.includes('250')) {
            console.error('Error sending email:', info);
            return res.status(500).send('Error sending email');
        }

        return res.status(200).send('RSVP Submitted');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in /api/rsvp:', error);
        logger.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});

app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/giftregistry', giftRegistryRoutes);
app.use('/location', locationRoutes);

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    logger.info(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    logger.info('Received SIGTERM, closing server gracefully');
    server.close(() => {
        logger.info('Server closed');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

*** This is what is in the terminal

```
[2023-11-27 23:33:33] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.9.7; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.9.7[client:6.9.7])
{"level":"info","message":"listening on http://localhost:8000"}
[2023-11-27 23:33:33] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] Resolved smtp.mail.yahoo.com as 67.195.12.42 [cache miss]
[2023-11-27 23:33:33] INFO  [K9zMITXi2fo] Secure connection established to 67.195.12.42:465
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] C: EHLO [127.0.0.1]
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 250-hermes--production-gq1-5cf8f76c44-42dfr Hello [127.0.0.1] [76.168.71.110])
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 250-PIPELINING
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 250-8BITMIME
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 250-SIZE 41697280
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] SMTP handshake finished
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] C: AUTH PLAIN AHdpbGxpYW1zc2hhbnRlbDM1QHlhaG9vLmNvbQAvKiBzZWNyZXQgKi8=[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] INFO  [K9zMITXi2fo] User "williamsshantel35@yahoo.com" authenticated
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] C: QUIT
Nodemailer is ready to send emails: true
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] S: 221 Service Closing transmission
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] DEBUG [K9zMITXi2fo] Closing connection to the server using "end"
[2023-11-27 23:33:34] INFO  [K9zMITXi2fo] Connection closed
 ***
```

This is my code snippet I'm making a website for wedding invitations, and I have an RSVP for that lets the users rsvp. I'm trying to make my code send an email to the email address provided (will have an actual email) with a notification saying someone rsvp'd. The problem that comes up is the connection keeps closing prematurely.

Comment: which connection? from your browser to your server? what is the http status of the request in the browser? do any of those console.log's occur?

Comment: the server connection. the https status is 200. once i run the server in the console it closes right after.

Comment: oh, so the server code isn't even running? what does `the server connection. the https status is 200` even mean? so, you do send an email, but there's no console.log when the status is 200, there are several console.log before that, are you saying they don't get output?

Comment: No an email is not sending because the server closes prematurely. so in the terminal the server is closing before I even get to send an email. I said the status is 200 because the website is running. and I'm not getting any 400 or 404 errors.

Comment: so, is the website being served by a different server to the code you've shown here? If so, the 200 status is for your web page loading, not the attempted email, since your email server isn't even running ... so when you try to run the email server, it simply stops without any output? neither `Nodemailer is ready to send emails` nor `Nodemailer verification error`?

Comment: the email server is on localhost 8000 and the web page is localhost 3000. yes the email server just stops with no output

Comment: add some more console.log's to see where the issue is, especially above any `logger.info` where you haven't already got a console.log

Comment: when I run the server I get this logged in the console: Nodemailer is ready to send emails: true. I would show you everything in the console, but this chat box doesn't take a lot of characters.

Comment: Well, that's why you can edit your question and add any pertinent info in there - the fact that `listening on http://localhost:${PORT}` isn't output suggests something happens that you aren't aware of - e.g., I do `app.listen(port, (error) => { if (error) { return console.error(error);} ...` when I use expressjs - to see if there's any errors when trying to start the server  listener - my guess is, there's an error there, which you ignore

Comment: i will do that now. this is my first time using stack overflow . and im new to coding all together.

Comment: that `Connection closed` is just the connection used to test the email transport, perfectly OK for that to occur there - please check if `app.listen` calls back with an error - also, double check which port is being used `console.log(PORT)` just after `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;`

Comment: I did the console.log(PORT) and the port is 8000. Also there is no callback error.

Comment: So weird ... what about  `console.log(server)` - just before `server.on(....` does that output a whole bunch of things (doesn't matter what)

Comment: yes i tried that too and it did output alot of things

Comment: wow, so I wonder why your code just stops running ...

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out lol.

Comment: Sure, but it wasn't obvious from the original question that the server code simply wasn't running at all - personally, I'd remove (comment out) a lot of the cruft ... helmet, helmetCSP, rateLimit and winston and perhaps all those other routes, just to see if any of those are the reason the server just won't start properly - you just want that `listening on http://localhost:${PORT}` to be output, then slowly add in the other stuff until it doesn't work any more :p

Comment: Ok cool I'll try that thanks a lot. next time I ask a question I'll make sure to format my questions better.